# Spring @Value Problem in Custom ConstraintValidator for Unit Testing

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm using Spring version 4.1.6.RELEASE. I have the following custom ConstraintValidator.

```
public class CountryCodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CountryCode, String> {
    private List<String> allowedCountries;

    @Autowired
    public void setAllowedCountries(@Value("${allowed.countries}")String countries) {
        allowedCountries = Arrays.asList(countries.split(","));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(CountryCode constraintAnnotation) {  }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String countryCode, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        return null != countryCode && allowedCountries.contains(countryCode.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

and I have the following annotation

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CountryCodeValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CountryCode {

    String message() default "{CountryCode}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I'm using this in a request object like the following

```
@CountryCode(message = MessageKeys.COUNTRY_CODE_INVALID)
private String countryCode;
```

When I run the application, everything is working as expected. However in the unit test for the controller it is failing.

My unit test code is like the following

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/test-context.xml")
public class ControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Controller controller;

  @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
    public void testEndpoint()  {
        Request request = new Request();
        RestAssuredMockMvc.given().standaloneSetup(controller).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).body(request)
                .post("/endpoint").then().statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }
}
```

When I run the code I could not get **@Value("${allowed.countries}")**, therefore I'm receiving a null pointer exception in the isValid method.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like `@ContextConfiguration` is messing up your configuration. Have you defined a value for your `allowed.countries` property in the `test-context.xml` context?

Comment: test has its own resources, so i think you need to specify the allowed.countries value in the test's properties file as well if you haven't already.

Comment: The problem is `standAloneSetup` is not initializing the `@Value`. I used `webAppContextSetup` and it worked.